# Refreshing list After Deleting data Data is not refresh in mui-datatables

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I simply delete one data using my delete API with the icon  onClick event and after that, I simply call my list API but the list is not updated I have to refresh that page or simply double click on my icon then list call updates.

When I debug my code then I notice that API call coming with the response of 304 after deleting the successful message.

This happens only in delete functionality.

Here is Code.

Icon

```
<i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg" id={data._id} onClick={(e) => this.deletedata(e.target.id)}  ></i>
```

Delete Function

```
 deletedata = (data) => {
        debugger;
        this.props.DeleteCity(data);<----Delete Api Call
        this.props.getcity();<----- Get Api Call 
    }
```

Note:-
1. API is made in Node on the backend side and Front side using redux-saga for API calls.
2. And please note that API is not yet Uploaded on any server I am using them in the same system with help of cross-environment setup.

Comment: I think i cud be able to help if I can see a little bit more code than this. By the way, did you use any component lifecycle method? Such as ComponentDidUpdate()? Maybe that will do the work? Let me know @Brahmrshi R

Comment: @Maurice which Part of code you please let me know I will share that with you

Comment: Is it possible to show all the code in the .js file? So me & others will have a clear vision of what u want to achieve. @Brahmrshi R

Comment: @MauricePheyton Hey bro thanks for advice ComponentDidUpdate() is helpful for me I totally forget about it. Thanks

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that! @Brahmrshi R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't happen because it doesn't work asynchronously.

```
 deletedata = async (data) => {
        debugger;
        await this.props.DeleteCity(data);<----Delete Api Call
        this.props.getcity();<----- Get Api Call 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For Suggestion Its also Helpful for me And its also work perfectly